# How to use information from Google Forms/Docs in Docusign and vice versa?

Tags: google-apps-script, docusignapi, google-docs-api, google-sheets-api

I would like to use information from a Google Form (upon submission) to send an envelope from a template using the Docusign api.

After the envelope is completed, I want to send out a different Google Form and a Google Doc to the same person. In addition, I would like to send some emails after steps are completed.

I have looked at using Google Apps Script, which works for Forms, Docs and emails, but I can't figure out how to run the Docusign api from there. Any help is greatly appreciated.

UPDATE: based on your help I have come up with the following. When I run the code below I get a error reading: "The specified Integrator Key was not found or is disabled. An Integrator key was not specified.". The integrator key is active, but could it have someting to do with the redirect URI or the secret key? I do not have them set-up.

```
// When Form Gets submitted

function onFormSubmit(e) {

//Get information from form and set our variables 

  var full_name = e.values[2];
  var email_address = e.values[3];

// Send the email

  var subject = "TEST trigger";
  var body    = "Thank you for testing" + full_name + "";

  MailApp.sendEmail(email_address, 
                    subject, 
                    body); 

// SEND DOCUSIGN ENVELOPE FROM TEMPLATE

   var url = "https://demo.docusign.net/restApi/v2/accounts/<accountid>/envelopes";

   var payload =
   {
  "emailSubject": "Please sign stuff",
  "emailBlurb": "TesttextTesttextTesttextTesttextTesttext",
  "templateId": "<templateID>",
  "templateRoles": [
    {
      "roleName": "role1",
      "name": full_name,
      "email": email_address
    },
    {
      "roleName": "role2",
      "name": "John Doe",
      "email": "JohnDoe@email.com"
    },
    {
      "roleName": "role3",
      "name": "Joe Smith",
      "email": "joesmith@email.com"
    }
  ],
  "status": "sent"
   }

   var options =
   {
     "method" : "post",
     "header": 
     {
    "X-DocuSign-Authentication": "{\"Username\":\<username>\",\"Password\":\"<passwork>\",\"IntegratorKey\":\"<integratorkey>\"}"
  },
     "payload" : payload
   };

   UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
 }
```

UPDATE: I changed `header` to `headers`, but now I get a different error. Ergin, as you suggested I logged the request. Below is the error message. It seems that there is something wrong with the content-type.

```
POST https://demo.docusign.net:7802/restApi/v2/accounts/<accountID>/envelopes

TraceToken: <token>
Timestamp: 2016-10-24T07:24:27.6912557Z

Content-Length: 187
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Connection: Keep-alive
Host: demo.docusign.net
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0(compatible; Google-Apps-Script)
X-DocuSign-Authentication: {"Username":"<my email address>","Password":"[omitted]","IntegratorKey":"[omitted]"}
X-BROKER-EVENT-ID: AHI413UAlYti8n93Pw-ZxoDmQoiCcwanMroRR1LDTgseOKFBkZVomEVZwdxJ-kajUMDC4NN__Z7e
X-Forwarded-For: 107.178.203.22
X-SecurityProtocol-Version: TLSv1.2
X-SecurityProtocol-CipherSuite: ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384

emailBlurb=TesttextTesttextTesttextTesttextTesttext&templateRoles=%5BLjava.lang.Object;@17be0aa5&templateId=7078020e-49a0-42c6-b77d-368211d4a666&emailSubject=Please+sign+stuff&status=sent
415 UnsupportedMediaType
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8

{
  "errorCode": "INVALID_CONTENT_TYPE",
  "message": "Content Type specified is not supported."
}
```

UPDATE: after setting the content-type, I got an error that the body was improperly formatted. See below

```
POST https://demo.docusign.net:7802/restApi/v2/accounts/<accountid>/envelopes

TraceToken: 0304eb5f-1188-4880-a22c-861839f4e8d9
Timestamp: 2016-10-25T09:40:49.0423980Z

Content-Length: 187
Content-Type: application/json
Connection: Keep-alive
Host: demo.docusign.net
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0(compatible; Google-Apps-Script)
X-DocuSign-Authentication: {"Username":"<email>","Password":"[omitted]","IntegratorKey":"[omitted]"}
X-BROKER-EVENT-ID: AHI413WWv-VgeLRQbOpMQH-Y6J-93aHL4h5phAVpXeXUqK8RsYof90Eu68CI-LkC1Ef4FM8Hac-1
X-Forwarded-For: 107.178.192.41
X-SecurityProtocol-Version: TLSv1.2
X-SecurityProtocol-CipherSuite: ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
Accept: application/json

emailBlurb=TesttextTesttextTesttextTesttextTesttext&templateRoles=%5BLjava.lang.Object;@3449f174&templateId=7078020e-49a0-42c6-b77d-368211d4a666&emailSubject=Please+sign+stuff&status=sent
400 BadRequest
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8

{
  "errorCode": "INVALID_REQUEST_BODY",
  "message": "The request body is missing or improperly formatted. Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: e. Path '', line 0, position 0."
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your request will of course vary based on a few factors like how many recipients and tabs (fields) but at the basic level to send a signature request from a template you need to make an http POST request to the envelopes URI with the template info in the request body:

```
POST https://demo.docusign.net/restApi/v2/accounts/{accountId}/envelopes

{
    "status": "sent",
    "emailSubject": "Request a signature via email example",
    "templateId": "44D9E888-3D86-4186-8EE9-7071BC87A0DA",
    "templateRoles": [
        {
            "email": "sally.doe@email.com",
            "name": "John Dough",
            "roleName": "RoleOne",
            "tabs": {
                "textTabs": [
                    {
                        "tabLabel": "ApplicantName",
                        "value": "John Dough"
                    },
                    {
                        "tabLabel": "ApplicantSSN",
                        "value": "12-345-6789"
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

You can test the Envelopes: create API through the [DocuSign API Explorer](https://apiexplorer.docusign.com/#/?categories=Envelopes&tags=Envelopes&operations=create&mode=basic).

Comment: Thanks Ergin. I can do this from my Google App Script?

Comment: Hi @Ergin, I just posted an update. Could you have a look?

Comment: The error message is telling you it can't find your Integrator Key in the request, I would check and ensure your auth header is getting attached properly assuming you're passing a valid key.  I see you've added a `header` node to add the header, normally that should be plural `headers`.  Try changing to that and if that doesn't work then you should enable request logging in your account and run a trace so you can inspect the incoming request.

Comment: Thanks Ergin, the `header` instead of `headers` was the first hurdle. Unfortunately, I now get another error saying there is a problem with the content type. See update above. Could this have something to do with the format of the payload?

Comment: Try adding a `content-type` header and set it to `application/json`.  If that doesn't work as previously mentioned trace your request then post the raw request in your question.

Comment: It seems like there is something wrong with the way the body request is being sent. Maybe something in the formatting?

Comment: I have tried a couple of different other things, but I keep getting the same eror. Can you offer any more advise?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Class ItemResponse](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/item-response) to get the response to one question item within a form. Item responses can be accessed from [`FormResponse`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form-response.html) and created from any Item that asks the respondent to answer a question.

Here is a sample code snippet:

```
// Open a form by ID and log the responses to each question.
var form = FormApp.openById('1234567890abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz');
var formResponses = form.getResponses();
for (var i = 0; i < formResponses.length; i++) {
  var formResponse = formResponses[i];
  var itemResponses = formResponse.getItemResponses();
   for (var j = 0; j < itemResponses.length; j++) {
     var itemResponse = itemResponses[j];
     Logger.log('Response #%s to the question "%s" was "%s"',
         (i + 1).toString(),
         itemResponse.getItem().getTitle(),
         itemResponse.getResponse());
   }
}
```

***...but I can't figure out how to run the Docusign api from there.***

You can check this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/external) since Google Apps Script can interact with APIs from all over the web. If you want to use a Google or non-Google API that isn't available as an Apps Script service, you can connect to the API's public HTTP interface through the [URL Fetch service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch).

> This service allows scripts to access other resources on the web by fetching URLs. A script can use the UrlFetch service to issue HTTP and HTTPS requests and receive responses. The UrlFetch service uses Google's network infrastructure for efficiency and scaling purposes.

Hope this helps!